# Can you translate data pulled with NFC to a different language?

Tags: java, android

Is there a way for the data I read from a NFC tag to then be able to translate that data into a choice of my own? For example, I scan a tag with direction data on it. How can I choose which language I wish to read that data in?

Answer (score 0):

NFC tags don't have much memory. And the ones that do have more memory are much more expensive.

And so sometimes data is represented with a short hexadecimal number. In the case of transit data for instance, in San Francisco this [application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.codebutler.farebot) called Farebot will be able to tell you which Bart Station you got in and which Bart Station you exited (BART stands for Bay Area Rapid Transit, it's a type of medium-range subway train that connects multiple cities within the Bay Area).

But instead of storing "16th Street Mission" inside the transit card, it might only store a shorter hexadecimal number like B2

And inside the Farebot application, there would already be an internal table that knows that B2 is equivalent to "16th Street Mission" for instance, but depending on the language setting of your app, there is no reason that you couldn't have a French table that tells you that B2 corresponds to "16eme Rue Mission" also.

Does my explanation make sense? Unfortunately, with the limited memory of NFC tags, you can't store too much data within the tag/card itself, and so storing multiple translations inside the tag itself wouldn't make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question fine.

** NFC tags have very little memory, so you might have to build a dictionary in your application

For ex:
A1 is mapped to Right
B1 is mapped to Left. etc

Then you store A1 or B1 for example on your tags.

Then what you need to do is, when you resolve the A1 to Right after that you need to call a Translate API like

[Google translate](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs)

[Bing](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/translator/translatorapi.aspx) FREE

Answer (score 0):

It's the case that NFC tags can only hold limited amounts of data (think very small chunks of data) exactly as Stephan above said. To see you an example of another app made using NFC tags, kindly go to [this repo](https://github.com/aml2610/autolec/tree/master/app/src/main/java/ataa/warwickhack2016) and see the MainActivity, more precisely what's inside the if-statement starting from line 114 (I would've pasted the code, but it's not formatted properly). What it does is it gets the data from the tag and esentially translates it into a string that, if I remember well, was only something like (LR1, LR2, LR3...) and so on. How you "interpret" this tiny bit of information should be entirely on your app's backend code (e.g. we knew that LR1 was lecture room 1 so we had an idea of what to do). 
What I'm trying to say is that you can encode hexadecimal strings of limited length on the NFC and then convert it back to whatever data structure you want to use, but the logic and interpretation take place on your app's side. The repo above shows an example on how to do this in java.